# No Input to Open Drain Buffer, yet Output Drives Low?

Tags: input, buffer

I'm kind of stuck with understanding why the output of an open drain buffer is going low when there is nothing connected to the input. We're using the SN74LVC1G07. Truth table states that if the input is low, output will be low; if the input is high, output will be high impedance. How is it that when there is no electrical connection on the input of the buffer, the output will still be low? Shouldn't the output also be high impedance since the inverter doesn't have a valid input? Does an open connection actually constitute as a low?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmnUSO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: From the [Fine Manual](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g07.pdf?ts=1639598565316&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), section 11.1: `input pins should not be left unconnected because the undefined voltages
at the outside connections result in undefined operational states`. An open-circuit on the input is an invalid condition and results in an unpredictable output.

Comment: "Don't Care" is an illegal input state!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SN74LVC1G07 is a CMOS device.

With no connection to the input it could be taken as a high or a low. You need to put a high-value resistor between the input of the gate and ground. A value such as 10k would probably be suitable. This resistor is usually called a pull-down. A pull-up would be connected to the power-supply to give a logic 1.

With any logic you should always ensure that inputs are set to a known value at all times. The device may work as expected but even then it would be susceptible to interference and may change randomly.

Comment: Thanks. I also see that from brhans reply that they tell you not to leave the input floating in the layout section, which I ignored thinking my answer wouldn't be under layout. Lesson learned to read the whole thing!

Comment: It’s generally known you don’t leave cmos inputs floating on just about any cmos device. On the old bipolar ttl logic devices the input would default high due to the inherent design, it also meant that you’d use 400uA to pull it low. With cmos the input current is so low even looking at it can affect it ( probably not entirely true but moving your hand nearby etc can cause weird effects). If your switch is off board, you might need to consider extra protection for ESD etc.

Answer (score 2):

An unconnected CMOS input is undefined. It can be high or low. So what you see is completely realistic, the output can be in either state.

The input does not know it has a valid or invalid input, so therefore it cannot leave the output in high-z mode.